# Xcode Segmentation Fault 11 (custom url)

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, nsstring, segmentation-fault

Overview of project:
I am currently working on Unity iOS and sending info between 2 apps that I am working on using customURL. App A sends data to App B successfully and App B stores the data receive in a static variable. However, when app finish launching up and tries to retrieve the data (NSString*), segmentation fault 11 occurs (App Crash).

New to Xcode and I am totally clueless as to solving the segmentation fault. Kindly guide me to solve the problem. Thank you.

CustomUrlContoller.mm

```
#import "CustomURLController.h"
#import <stdio.h>
#import <stdlib.h>

@implementation CustomURLUnity
static int AccountID = -1;
static NSString *AccountIgn = @"";
+(void)SetAccount:(int)NewID AccIgn:(NSString*)NewIgn
{
    AccountID = NewID;
    AccountIgn = NewIgn;
}

+(int)GetAccountID { return AccountID; }
+(NSString*)GetAccountIgn { return AccountIgn; }
@end

extern "C" {
    int GetAccID() { return [CustomURLUnity GetAccountID]; }  //WORKS

    char* GetAccIGN() {
        NSLog(@"GetAccIGN: %@", [CustomURLUnity GetAccountIgn]);  //CRASH
        NSString* IgnString = [CustomURLUnity GetAccountIgn];
        if(IgnString isEqual:[NSNull null]])
        {
             IgnString = @"";
        }
        const char* stringAsChar = [IgnString UTF8String];
        char* cpy = (char*)calloc(1, [IgnString length]+1);
        strncpy(cpy, stringAsChar, [IgnString  length]);
        return cpy;
    }
}
```

UnityAppController.mm

```
#import "CustomURLController.h"
-(BOOL) application:(UIApplication*)application openURL:(NSURL*)url
        sourceApplication:(NSString*)sourceApplication
        annotation(id)annotation
{
    /*...default...*/
    if([sourceApplication isEqualToString:@"com.xxx.xxx"])
    {
        NSString* QueryStrings = [url query];
        NSArray* AccountStrings = [QueryStrings componentsSeparatedByString: @"&"];
        NSString* AccountID = [AccountStrings objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString* IGN = [AccountStrings objectAtIndex:1];
        int AccountIDNo = [AccountID intvalue];
        [CustomURLUnity SetAccount:AccountIDNo AccIgn:IGN];
        NSLog(@"openURL GetIgn: %@", [CustomURLUnity GetAccountIgn]);            
    }
    return YES;
}
```

The NSLog in openURL logs the Ign correctly according to input from the first App. However, when App B finish launching and tries to obtain the Ign by calling the extern method "GetAccIGN", App B crashes with segmentation fault 11.

The extern method "GetAccID" returns the AccountID successfully as according to input.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, found a solution to my problem.
It seems that the NSString* was dereferenced after openURL was called.
Therefore when I tried to called the NSString*, the pointer was not pointing to any memory location causing the segmentation fault.

To solve the segmentation fault, I have to make a copy of the NSString when it was set to the variable.

```
+(void)SetAccount:(int)NewID AccIgn:(NSString*)NewIgn
{
    AccountID = NewID;
    [AccountIgn release];  //Release the previous memory allocation
    AccountIgn = [NewIgn copy];  //Make a copy of the new string and assign
}
```